# Way to explode list into arguments?

Tags: scheme

Assume I have a procedure `upto` that when called like `(upto 1 10)` will generate the list `'(1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10)`.

If I want to use this list as arguments to a function like `lcm`  that takes multiple arguments rather than a single list, like `(lcm 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)` is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use apply: e.g

```
(apply lcm (upto 1 10))
```

"apply" applies a function to a list of arguments.

Comment: Ah, yes that seems cleaner than the way I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to do this using eval is the following:

(eval (cons 'lcm (upto 1 10)))

Comment: Yeah, in general, `eval` is to be avoided. There are very few legitimate uses of `eval` (a REPL is one of them), so any time you start to want to reach for `eval`, think harder. ;-)

Comment: Yes, don't ever do this. You made me gasp out loud.

Answer (score 0):

In MIT-Scheme (unsure of others) you can use the dot in your function definition.

```
(define (func-with-multiple-args . args)
  (let loop ((args args))
    (if (null? args)
      'done
      (begin (display (car args)) (loop (cdr args))))))
```

Calling with

```
(func-with-multiple-args 1 2 3 4)
```

will do the job. Note that the args get put into a list.

Fun fact: the `list' procedure is actually defined in list.scm of the MIT-Scheme "runtime" source as:

```
(define (list . args)
 args)
```