# Can Scheme expand a list as arguments?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Considered that I have a procedure `(plus x y)` witch takes exactly two args. And now I also have a list which contains two objects like `(list 1 2)`. So, if there's **any** magic way to expand the list as two arguments. We have a **dot notion** version, but that **isn't** what i want. I just want to expand the list to make Scheme believe I passed two arguments instead of a list.

Hope those Ruby codes help:

```
a = [1, 2]
def plus(x,y); x+y; end

plus(*a)
# See that a is an array and the plus method requires
# exactly two arguments, so we use a star operator to
# expand the a as arguments
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to explode list into arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483797/way-to-explode-list-into-arguments)

Comment: And remember you can curry with apply as well. E.g. instead of (apply map (cons list list-of-lists)) you do (apply map list list-of-lists)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(apply your-procedure your-list)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is Scheme's equivalent code:

```
(define (plus x y)
  (+ x y))

(plus 1 2)
=> 3

(define a (list 1 2))
(apply plus a)
 => 3
```

The "magic" way to expand the list and pass it as arguments to the procedure, is using `apply`. Read more about it your interpreter's [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29).